# Не работает ответ от java-servleta, на запрос от javascript по технологии ajax

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, servlet

Разбираюсь как работает ajax. Сделал свой пример.

Принцип работы примера: 
  html-форма при нажатии на кнопку Поиск запускает скрипт,который берет данные
из формы, формирует запрос к веб серверу TomCat на сервлет. Сервлет получает данные
из запроса на основании этих данных запускает методы доступа к БД получет данные из БД
формирует xml ответ(Список городов запрошенной страны/стран). 
Скрипт той же html-формы распознает этот ответ  Парсит его и на основании 
полученных данных формирует дополнительные данные на страничке формы.

**Проблема:** не всегда вижу ответ от java-servleta. Иногда он в консоли браузера проскакивает и скрипт формирует таблицу городов на странице, но тут же ее обновляет на исходную форму.

код формы:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Use and copying for commercial purposes
only with the author's permission
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>SearchCountryButtonAjax</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="text/html">
        <!-- ссылка на файл javascript.js-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body> <!-- <body onload="init()"> обеспечит выполнение вызова init() при каждой 
                          загрузке страницы --> 

        <form  name ="ajaxform" >
            <input id="country" size="40">           
            <input type="hidden" id="hiddenIndex" value="0">            
            <input type="submit" value="Поиск" onclick="doCompletion();">            
        </form>
        <table id="complete-table" >                            
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Код скрипта:

```
var req;
var isIE;
var completeField;//поле ввода символов
var completeTable;//таблица, выводящая в ответ список стран
//var autoRow;//строка в которую помещаем таблицу completeTable

//запрос на веб-сервер
function doCompletion() {
    completeField = document.getElementById("country");//возвращает из 
    //документа ссылку на элемент, который имеет атрибут id с указанным 
    //значением. В нашем случае это поле ввода текса
    completeIndex = document.getElementById("hiddenIndex");//возвращает из запроса
    // ссылку на элемент hiddenIndex (для пролистывания формируемого списка городов)
    completeTable = document.getElementById("complete-table");    
    /**
     * формируем строку для GET запроса к серверу через сервлет         * 
     * Url состоит из:
     * - имени сервлета к которому посылаем запрос
     * - передаваемого параметра  action (используется при идентификации 
     * запроса сервлетом)
     * - передаваемого параметра id
     * - передаваемого параметра index
     */
    var url = "ShowResultSearchAjaxServlet?action=requestComplete&id=" + escape(completeField.value) + "&index=" + escape(completeIndex.value);
//        var url = "ShowResultSearchAjaxServlet?action=requestComplete&id=" + escape(completeField.value);
    //создаем объект запроса
    req = initRequest();//метод вызывающий метод (который возвращает объект
    // XMLHttpRequest или ActiveXObject)
    // 
    //конфигурируем объект запроса
    req.open("GET", url, true);//тип запроса, строка адреса, асинхронный запрос
    /*
     * Если взаимодействие определено как асинхронное, необходимо указать 
     * функцию обратного вызова. Функция обратного вызова для этого 
     * взаимодействия определяется при помощи следующего оператора:        
     */
    req.onreadystatechange = callback; //функция обратного вызова callback,
    // которая будет вызываться при изменении состояния readyState 
    // объекта XMLHttpRequest нашего подготовленного запроса в процессе 
    // его дальнейшей отправки    

    req.send(null);//отсылаем запрос
}
// подготовка запроса для адаптации с браузером
function initRequest() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {//если возможно вызвать метод XMLHttpRequest
        //проверка на используемый браузер (MSIE)
        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') != -1) {
            isIE = true;
        }
        return new XMLHttpRequest();//то вызвваем его

    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {//иначе пробуем вызвать метод для MSIE
        isIE = true;
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");//и делаем это если это возможно 
    }
}
//функция обратного вызова, запускающая обработчик принятого ответа от веб-сервера
function callback() {    
    if (req.readyState == 4) {//состояние объекта XMLHttpRequest нашего запроса=запрос завершен и ответ готов 
//        alert("req.readyState=4");
        if (req.status == 200) {// код ответа на наш запрос =запрос обработан успешно
//            alert("req.readyState=4, req.status=200");
            parseMessages(req.responseXML);//парсим полученное в ответ сообщение
        }
    }
}
//добавляет страну в таблицу вывода
function appendCity(name) {

    var row;
    var cell;
    var linkElement;

    if (isIE) {
        completeTable.style.display = 'block';
        row = completeTable.insertRow(completeTable.rows.length);
        cell = row.insertCell(0);
    } else {
        completeTable.style.display = 'table';
        row = document.createElement("tr");
        cell = document.createElement("td");
        row.appendChild(cell);
        completeTable.appendChild(row);
    }

    cell.className = "popupCell";

    linkElement = document.createElement("a");
    linkElement.className = "popupItem";
    linkElement.setAttribute("href", "autocomplete?action=lookup&id=");
    linkElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
    cell.appendChild(linkElement);
}
//для выравнивания таблицы предложений
function getElementY(element) {

    var targetTop = 0;

    if (element.offsetParent) {
        while (element.offsetParent) {
            targetTop += element.offsetTop;
            element = element.offsetParent;
        }
    } else if (element.y) {
        targetTop += element.y;
    }
    return targetTop;
}
//очистка таблицы предложений поиска
function clearTable() {
    if (completeTable.getElementsByTagName("tr").length > 0) {
        completeTable.style.display = 'none';
        for (item = completeTable.childNodes.length - 1; item >= 0; item--) {
            completeTable.removeChild(completeTable.childNodes[item]);
        }
    }
}
//парсинг xml ответа веб-сервера
function parseMessages(responseXML) {

    // no matches returned
    if (responseXML == null) {
        return false;
    } else {

        //присваиваем первый элемент массива ссылок данного имени, 
        //найденных во всем xml документе
        var cities = responseXML.getElementsByTagName("cities")[0];

        if (cities.childNodes.length > 0) {
            console.log(cities.childNodes.length);
            completeTable.setAttribute("bordercolor", "black");
            completeTable.setAttribute("border", "1");     
            for (var item = 0; item < (cities.childNodes.length); item++) {
                var city = cities.childNodes[item];
                var name = city.getElementsByTagName("name")[0];//хранит ссылку на элемент name
                //добавляем в таблицу html страницы распаресенные данные
                  console.log(name.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                appendCity(name.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
               }
        }
    }
}
```

Код сервлета:

```
        @Override
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        String requestDB;
        requestDB = null;//передаваемое в запросе название страны
        //считываем данные из запроса
        requestDB = request.getParameter("id");//получение из запроса         
        //скрипта значения поля формы(введенное пользователем значение) 

//            if(requestDB==null){
//                requestDB=request.getParameter("requestDB");//считывание данных запроса
//            }   
        //считываем данные из запроса
        String action = request.getParameter("action");

        int index;//смещение запрашиваемых значений для sql запроса limit

        index = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("index"));//считывание данных запроса

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();//для временного сохранения строки (для формирования xml)

        //читаем из БД
        ctr5 = new CountriesTableReader();
//            ctr.createdb();

//        ArrayList<Country> countriesList = ctr5.readCountries();

        if (requestDB != null) {//если значение не нулевое
            requestDB = requestDB.trim().toLowerCase();//убираем спереди и в конце пробелы, и делаем все буквы прописными
        } else {
//            context.getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }

        //читаем из БД список городов для выбранной страны(стран), начиная с элемента 
        //index sql команды limit
        cities = ctr5.searchCitiesOfCountries(requestDB, index);

        //формируем ответ в виде xml
        boolean requestAdded = false;

        if (action.equals("requestComplete")) {//идентифицируем наш запрос из всех возможных запросов

            // проверяем что запрос не пустой
            if (!requestDB.equals("")) {

                //подготавливаем xml данные
                for (City itemcity : cities) {
                    sb.append("<city>");//                      
                    sb.append("<name>" + itemcity.getNameCity() + "</name>");//                       ;
                    sb.append("</city>");
                    requestAdded = true;
                }
            }

            if (requestAdded) {
                //если имена добавлены, то отправляем в ответ на запрос xml строку

                response.setContentType("text/xml");
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                response.getWriter().write("<cities>" + sb.toString() + "</cities>");//xml строка

                System.out.println("************");
//                System.out.println(sb.toString());
//                System.out.println(requestDB);
//                System.out.println("************");
//                System.out.println(request.getProtocol());

            } else {
                //nothing to show
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
            }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас возникает "состояние гонки" между ajax запросом и стандартным сабмитом формы. Отмените стандартную отправку формы:

```
<input type="button" value="Поиск" onclick="doCompletion();">
```

---

*P.S. Слишком много кода в вопросе.*

Comment: Спасибо большое. Заменил submit на button. Генерируемые в ответ данные перестали исчезать